# Overwrite filename in SetAttributesCallback in Azure Storage Data Movement Library

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I need to lowercase all filenames during UploadDirectoryAsync - is this possible to control or set via 'SetAttributesCallback'??

I cannot control the local physical files or rename them locally before uploading them to azure via Azure Storage Data Movement Library.

The end result will be that source and destination filename always will be with lowercase.

Any solution out there??

Answer (score 0):

> I need to lowercase all filenames during UploadDirectoryAsync - is this possible to control or set via 'SetAttributesCallback'

Yes, we could do that in the SetAttributesCallback, currently there is no rename [Azure blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Blob-Service-REST-API?redirectedfrom=MSDN), so we could upload the required renamed file in the SetAttributesCallback and delete the UploadDirectoryAsync load file. I also test it on my side, it works correctly.

The following is my demo code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement;

namespace DataMovementTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageConnectionString = "storage connection string";
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container name");
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            var destDir = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("directory name");
            string sourceDirPath = @"local path";
            var options = new UploadDirectoryOptions
            {
                Recursive = false,
                BlobType = BlobType.BlockBlob
            };
            using (MemoryStream journalStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                // Store the transfer context in a streamed journal.
                DirectoryTransferContext context = new DirectoryTransferContext(journalStream)
                {
                    SetAttributesCallback = (destination) =>
                    {
                        CloudBlob destBlob = destination as CloudBlob;
                        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(destBlob.Uri.Segments.Last(), "[A-Z]")) //check whether blobName contains uppercase
                        {
                            var path = sourceDirPath + $"/{destBlob.Uri.Segments.Last()}";
                            Console.WriteLine(path);
                            var renameBlob = destDir.GetBlockBlobReference(destBlob.Uri.Segments.Last().ToLower());
                            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
                            {
                                renameBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
                            }
                            destBlob.DeleteIfExists();
                        }

                    },

                    ShouldTransferCallback = (source, destination) => true

                };
                CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                try
                {
                    // Start the upload
                    var uploadResult = TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(sourceDirPath, destDir, options, context, cancellationSource.Token).Result;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The transfer is cancelled: {0}", e.Message);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Files in directory {0} uploading to {1} is finished.", sourceDirPath, destDir.Uri.ToString());

            }
        }

    }
}
```